# Новый запрос к MySQL при обновлении страницы

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Всем привет!

Подскажите как лучше поступить.

Есть форма, валидируется JavaScriptом. После данные пихаются в переменные и улетают POST запросом на файл *.php, в файле есть проверка на наличие переменный в массиве _POST, если переменные есть, происходит запись в БД MySQL. Проблема в том что если обновить страничку на которую прилетает пользователь, данные в MySQL записываются повторно. Подскажите как можно организовать проверку, чтобы при обновлении страницы, данные не записывались повторно.
Для чего это нужно, на сайте есть форма отзыва, пользователь набирает отзыв, указывает имя, отзыв, прикрепляет фотку. Далее данные валидируются и улетают в другой файл, в другом файле раскладываются по переменный, навешивается ID и флаг модерации.

Какие мои мысли:
Добавлять в таблицу некие данные которые можно вытягивать и ПК пользователя, допустим IP, допустим слепок браузера. Потом сравнивать.

Прошу AJAX пока не предлагать, он еще не изучен ТТ. Но если Вы будете настаивать и говорить что это совсем легко и круто, тогда ничего не остаётся.

Comment: @Mike а чего в комментарий, а не ответ?

Comment: @jekaby Написал в ответ. хотя для ответа надо бы более развернуто, но не готов ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. При получении POST запроса писать в базу и вместо готовой страницы пользователю отдавать redirect что бы он опять пришел GET'ом.
2. Проверять дубли информации по всем (или части) значений. Если это не представляется возможным заранее генерим некий уникальный ID, причем генерим при каждом открытии формы вне зависимости от того будет потом post или нет. И пишем при post в базу вместе с данными это значение и проверяем уникальность по нему.

Для гарантированного результата второй пункт необходим. Один первый 100% гарантии не даст.

Comment: Да, это решение с промежуточным файлом, пользователь прилетает туда с POST запросом, данные пихаются в MySQL, дальше пользователь быстренько улетает дальше ))) С ID решение адекватное, подумаю как можно сделать так что-бы ID генерился на основе неких особенностей устройства с которого на сайт залезает пользователь, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Alex У меня подобное используется, у меня там кассир вбивает деньги и нельзя что бы они прошли второй раз. Там при каждом открытии формы получается следующее значение из секвенса (оракловая замена автоинкрементным колонкам mysql), да, куча id улетает вникуда, но если сделать bigint он ооочень не скоро переполнится. Мне не оч. нравится идея с чем то привязанным к посетителю, надо же уникальность обеспечить, а если он две разные записи решит создать ...

Answer (score 0):

Если используете AJAX, то просто сделайте ресет формы. 
Если используете AJAX, то просто сделайте ресет формы.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'you_url',
  data:$('#formid').serialize(),
  method:'POST',
  success: function(r){
   alert('hallelujah');
   $('#formid')[0].reset();
}
});
```

Процесс выглядит так следующим образом. Валидируем, отправляем бэкэнду, при получении положительного ответа сбрасываем форму и сообщаем человеку, что все клево. Если он решит обновить страницу то увидит не заполненную форму.

Comment: Да, сейчас к сожалению уже не будет времени реализовать данный функционал с помощью AJAX, но обязательно вернусь к этому через недельку. Спасибо, код очень понятен для меня, буду развивать Ваш ответ. Еще раз спасибо.